# Situations in which a DELETE statement does not execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging

I have an ERP system which I'm trying to debug and at some point when issuing a command from frontend a set of queries is executed in SQL Server.

In the set of queries there is a `DELETE` statement that should execute and remove some records from a table, but for some reason those records are not removed.

I have tried a few situations to figure out why this doesn't happen.

1. I've tried locking the table with a large query issued both from a frontend command and from an explicit backend set of queries from SQL Server.
2. I've tried to review user access to the table and that is correct.
3. I've also taken into account problems with the network connection, but because there are more statements from the same set that have executed before/after this `DELETE` statement, I've kind of ruled this out.

Is there anything else I could look at, or if you know of any possibility in which a `DELETE` statement does not execute?

Any suggestion is helpful as I am trying to replicate the issue and I'm out of ideas.

**UPDATE:**

As per your request, this is the query

```
DELETE
FROM Payments
WHERE transactionID = 5005281
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I've ran profiler when issuing the command from frontend so if a `DELETE` statement is present in the queries, then it was not supresed by application logic. Also, there are no calls to stored procedures to suspect the record is begin reinserted after DELETE.

Comment: Check which relationships are present in the database. If you have PK_FK couples, the delete won't work

Comment: Check if there is a `ON DELETE` trigger on the table preventing deletion.

Comment: Also, you could `convert the DELETE query into a similar SELECT query with same filtering etc` and see if you get any results?

Comment: Are you committing the transaction in which the delete statements is handled?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I'm not sure if transactions are created for each statement that modifies the table or once for the entire set (although when an error occurrs when changing something from frontend all modifications are rollbacked, so I don't know if there is only 1 or more transactions in my statemtnt). I can only see the queries by running Profiler.

Comment: If execute that DELETE in management studio (on a restored backup) do the records get deleted or not? Also are you able to provide the code which executes the queries and DELETE statement?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Yes, the records are deleted on a restored backup. Sadly I cannot provide code, as I do not have access to it.

Comment: Can you run the profiler with all transaction events on? You need to add them in the events selection "Show all events" and then tick all that apply. And then see if there is a begin transaction and commit transaction event(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to identify whether:

- the DELETE does not execute (logic flow control issue, it takes the other IF branch...)
- the DELETE executes but does not affect any rows (WHERE clause or JOIN problem)
- the DELETE executes and errors and the error is silently suppressed (error handling problem)
- the DELETE executes but the effect is rolled back (transaction management problem)
- the DELETE executes but the effect is compensated by app (application logic problem)
- the DELETE does not execute because a previous error stops the request (again error handling problem)
- the DELETE executes but your verification is incorrect (PBCAK)

For troubleshooting, look at [SP:StmtStarting Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188243.aspx), [SQL:StmtStarting Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190242.aspx), [Exception Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187506.aspx), [User-Configurable Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175164.aspx), [`sp_trace_generateevent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177548.aspx) and of course, good ole' [`PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx).

We obviously cannot guess, you need to show some code.

Comment: I've ran profiler when executing commands in frontend, so if a DELETE statement is present in profiler then an issue with application logic is excluded (I've also checked if record is reinserted after, and it's not).

Comment: StmtCompleted events show the affected row count. Was it 0 or not, for the DELETE statement?